# Most efficient solution for intervals in Redux/React

Tags: performance, reactjs, timer, redux, intervals

Im developing an app with multiple timers/stopwatches - up to as many as 400 and is concerned about the performance for the rest of the app, and unnecessary renders.

All timers need to use a timestamp that's offset from the local time (Date.now()), and i want all timers to increment/decrement at the same time, once, every second.

The offset is stored in the redux store.

---

### SOLUTION A

Would it be best to have a main timestamp stored in a top-level component and make that available to every child component. It would then update every second, with one interval like this:

```
currentTimestampFromToplevelComponent = Math.round((Date.now() - globalOffsetFromRedux) / 1000) * 1000
```

Every component would then be able to render this:

```
elapsedTime = currentTimestampFromToplevelComponent - componentsStartingTimestamp
```

---

### SOLUTION B

...or would the performance be better with each component having its own interval that run every 100ms, and each component would render this:

```
elapsedTime = Math.round(Date.now() - globalOffsetFromRedux / 1000) * 1000 - componentsStartingTimestamp
```

---

A: One interval every second, but lots of property updates.
B: Many intervals every 100 ms, but few property updates.

Comment: none of it show any rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

none of it show any rendering?

from what I can understand:

solution A: there is global elapsedTime as a state, and after this state changes, React will then render down to  all children component;

Solution B, each component has it's own elapsedTime as a state, so each component will render itself for every state changes,

I think it is always better to reduce the amount of state. solution A

Comment: Apologies for the lack of precision. The code above will be in the renderfunctions and will execute on every render. The value elapsedTime will be independent for every child component as the componentsStartingTimestamp will differ from child to child, and is in the state of the component. elapsedTime is rendered to the user as seconds. The main difference between the two solutions are that the Date.now() is placed higher up the tree in solution A, and possibly making unneccessery components rerender, but will at least do it simultaniously for alle the timers/stopwatches.

Comment: Most people put the states higher up on the tree, you have actually already mimicking flux architecture, try to read about flux. By this time, it should be easy for you to understand flux; however try redux for simpler architecture. Back to  your question, it is solution A.